# Test for proportions

Tags: chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, proportion

I have the following data: 
30 schools were chosen from 20 countries, where in each school $i$ from each country $j$ I have the total number of students: $n_{i,j}$ and the number of vegetarian students among them $k_{i,j}$. My null hypothesis for each country $j$ is that there are no sampling biases. In other words, under the null I expect the proportion of vegetarian students in each sampled school to be very close to the average proportion across schools in that country. I therefore define my null expected proportion of vegetarian students for each country ($\hat{p}_j$) as the average proportion of vegetarian students across all schools of that country ($\hat{p}_j$ = ${\sum_{i=1}^{30}p_{i,j}/30}$). Therefore, my null hypothesis is: $p_{j,1}$ = $p_{j,2}$ = $p_{j,3}$ = ... = $p_{j,30}$ $\forall$ $j$.

How should I test for each country $j$ whether the null hypothesis can be rejected?

The first thing that comes to mind is a Chi-square test where the observed number of vegetarian students in each school $i$ of country $j$ is $k_{i,j}$ and the expected number of vegetarian students is $\hat{p}_j$*$n_{i,j}$. The problem is that the schools in these countries are very big (dozens of thousands of students) and therefore with such high counts the null hypothesis is easily rejected.

What is the optimal way to test my hypothesis, ideally in a way that is not so sensitive to the high number of students?

Comment: The null hypothesis must be chosen in advance. It doesn't make sense to test a null hypothesis picked after you see the data. It would help to state your scientific goal, as the question is not really clear now.